# __NSCFDictionary doesn't respond to any selectors

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to Parse JSON that looks like this:

```
food =     {
    "food_id" = 4823;
    servings =         {
        serving =             (
                            {
                calcium = 9;
                calories = 221;
                carbohydrate = "16.20";
                cholesterol = 31;
```

I can successfully retrieve the array at the `[food][servings][serving]` level, which I confirm via a log statement has the appropriate class, `__NSCFArray`,  but I run into a problem when iterating through that array and trying to do useful things with the contained information:

```
  for (id foodId in resultsPerServing) {
        NSLog(@"hree is a result %@", foodId);
        foodObjectClass *foodObject = [foodObjectClass new];
        NSDictionary *foodIdDictionary = (NSDictionary *)foodId;
        if ([foodIdDictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(allKeys)]) {
            [foodObject getDetailsFromResponseObject:foodIdDictionary];
        } else {
            unsigned int mc = 0;
            Method * mlist = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(foodIdDictionary), &mc);
            NSLog(@"%d methods", mc);
            for(int i=0;i<mc;i++)
                NSLog(@"Method no #%d: %s", i, sel_getName(method_getName(mlist[i])));

            [NSException raise:@"DIDN'T GET A DICTIONARY" format:@"here is the object %@ which has class %@", resultsPerServing, [responseObject class]];
        }

}
```

This causes the `NSException` to be raised without fail although in the NSException the output from printing the object looks like a dictionary. Additionally, when the exception prints out the class of the object which does not respond to `allKeys`, that object has class `__NSCFDictionary`. **What gives? Why does this dictionary not have an allKeys method and how can I get a functional dictionary to work with?**

Even more puzzling is that the runtime code below (copied from an SO post for which I have lost the link) indicates that the dictionary has 0 methods. **Why does this object have no methods? How can I get an object that does have methods?**

Comment: Update your question with the actual, copy and pasted log output. Also, log `[foodId class]`.

Answer (score -1):

make a check to confirm that it as NSDictionary first?

```
 if ([foodId isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]  ) {
    foodIdDictionary = (NSDictionary *)foodId;
    [foodObject getDetailsFromResponseObject:foodIdDictionary];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I did that. Same results.

Comment: so [foodIdDictionary allKeys] raise exception ? did you pull some data out of it and try to call allKeys on it or some thing cause  [foodIdDictionary allKeys] should not raise exception

Comment: Yes it raises an exception. I know it shouldn't but it does. That's why I posted my question.